# How to do properly a full Outer Join of two RDDs with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, outer-join

I'm looking for a way to combine two RDDs by key.

Given :

```
x = sc.parallelize([('_guid_YWKnKkcrg_Ej0icb07bhd-mXPjw-FcPi764RRhVrOxE=', 'FR', '75001'),
                ('_guid_XblBPCaB8qx9SK3D4HuAZwO-1cuBPc1GgfgNUC2PYm4=', 'TN', '8160'),
               ]
              )
y = sc.parallelize([('_guid_oX6Lu2xxHtA_T93sK6igyW5RaHH1tAsWcF0RpNx_kUQ=', 'JmJCFu3N'),
                ('_guid_hG88Yt5EUsqT8a06Cy380ga3XHPwaFylNyuvvqDslCw=', 'KNPQLQth'),
                ('_guid_YWKnKkcrg_Ej0icb07bhd-mXPjw-FcPi764RRhVrOxE=', 'KlGZj08d'),
               ]
              )
```

I found a solution ! Nevertheless, this solution is not entirely satisfactory for what I want to do.
I created a function in order to specify my key which will be applied to my rdd named "x" :

```
def get_keys(rdd):

    new_x = rdd.map(lambda item: (item[0], (item[1], item[2])))
    return new_x

new_x = get_keys(x)
```

which gives :

```
[('_guid_YWKnKkcrg_Ej0icb07bhd-mXPjw-FcPi764RRhVrOxE=', ('FR', '75001')),
 ('_guid_XblBPCaB8qx9SK3D4HuAZwO-1cuBPc1GgfgNUC2PYm4=', ('TN', '8160'))]
```

Then :

```
new_x.union(y).map(lambda (x, y): (x, [y])).reduceByKey(lambda p, q : p + q).collect()
```

The result :

```
[('_guid_oX6Lu2xxHtA_T93sK6igyW5RaHH1tAsWcF0RpNx_kUQ=', ['JmJCFu3N']),
 ('_guid_YWKnKkcrg_Ej0icb07bhd-mXPjw-FcPi764RRhVrOxE=', [('FR', '75001'), 'KlGZj08d']),
 ('_guid_XblBPCaB8qx9SK3D4HuAZwO-1cuBPc1GgfgNUC2PYm4=', [('TN', '8160')]),
 ('_guid_hG88Yt5EUsqT8a06Cy380ga3XHPwaFylNyuvvqDslCw=', ['KNPQLQth'])]
```

What I want to have is :

```
[('_guid_oX6Lu2xxHtA_T93sK6igyW5RaHH1tAsWcF0RpNx_kUQ=', (None, None, 'JmJCFu3N')),
 ('_guid_YWKnKkcrg_Ej0icb07bhd-mXPjw-FcPi764RRhVrOxE=', ('FR', '75001', 'KlGZj08d')),
 ('_guid_XblBPCaB8qx9SK3D4HuAZwO-1cuBPc1GgfgNUC2PYm4=', ('TN', '8160', None)),
 ('_guid_hG88Yt5EUsqT8a06Cy380ga3XHPwaFylNyuvvqDslCw=', (None, None, 'KNPQLQth'))]
```

Help ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not?

```
>>> new_x.fullOuterJoin(y)
```

or

```
>>> x.toDF().join(y.toDF(), ["_1"], "fullouter").rdd
```

Comment: LostInOverflow : x.toDF().join(y.toDF(), ["_1"], "fullouter").rdd.collect() gives : [Row(_1=u'_guid_YWKnKkcrg_Ej0icb07bhd-mXPjw-FcPi764RRhVrOxE=', _2=u'FR', _3=u'75001', _2=u'KlGZj08d')]. new_x.fullOuterJoin(y) is better.

Comment: [('_guid_oX6Lu2xxHtA_T93sK6igyW5RaHH1tAsWcF0RpNx_kUQ=', (None, 'JmJCFu3N')),
 ('_guid_YWKnKkcrg_Ej0icb07bhd-mXPjw-FcPi764RRhVrOxE=',
>>> new_x.fullOuterJoin(y) ======>  (('FR', '75001'), 'KlGZj08d')),
 ('_guid_XblBPCaB8qx9SK3D4HuAZwO-1cuBPc1GgfgNUC2PYm4=',
  (('TN', '8160'), None)),
 ('_guid_hG88Yt5EUsqT8a06Cy380ga3XHPwaFylNyuvvqDslCw=', (None, 'KNPQLQth'))]

Comment: Is there a way to separate 'FR' and '75001' in (('FR', '75001'), 'KlGZj08d') ?

Comment: `Row` is a tuple. names are only a display sugar.  Regarding the second: `mapValues(lambda x: x[0] + (x[1], ))`?